# import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, apple-m1

I receive this error in Python 3.9.1

```py
import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

But when I install pandas in the terminal it.

Comment: in your terminal type `which pip` (or whichever `pip` you presumably used for `pip install pandas`)

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple python versions installed? In that case try `python3.9 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: I believe that was the problem, multiple versions of pip

Comment: run this command      ::     **pip3 install pandas**

Answer (score 1):

Please check the interpreter your using while trying to `import pandas` and receiving this error. This is probably a multiple python versions problem. Type in terminal `which python3` or `which <what ever python you use>` and then (it differs by the ide you use) check if both pythons point to the same path.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to install pandas directly into jupyter notebook in anaconda navigator like this:

```
%pip install pandas
```

Comment: I just edited this to encourage best practices in modern Jupyter. Use of the exclamation point for installing with `pip` or `conda` is no longer advised as magic commands have been added that are meant to overcome the shortcomings use of an exclamation point suffers when dealing with environments. Use of the modern magics `%pip install` or `%conda install` inside a cell in the notebook insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the notebook kernel. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more.